# Only one parent page showing

Tags: child-pages

I'm working with the Incubator theme. I have created two other parent pages but they come up blank, with no content.

The only way they show content is if I set them, one at a time, as the homepage in

> Customize > Homepage Settings > Homepage

.

Is this the correct behaviour? Is only one parent page allowed per Wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

More than one parent page can be used. Only the actual home page should be set using the setting described above.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with my WP installation and I cannot find what it is.